# Bike Rack for Hatchback vehicle?

Tags: touring, rack, car-rack

I have a hatchback-style Vehicle (2007 Ford Focus) and a KHS Urban-X Bicycle.

- Are there any standard styles of mount that work best in this situation?
- Can you recommend any in particular or point me towards particular styles?

Thanks!

Comment: There was an extensive survey thread on vehicle bike racks about 6 months back.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, I couldn't find it; could you link? Might be helpful to others on this thread in the future.

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/8137/313  -- Covers racks in general pretty well

Comment: *Possible* duplicate: [Best bike rack for Hinda Pilot](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5829/best-bike-rack-for-honda-pilot).

Comment: Not the one I was thinking of, but: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/pros-and-cons-of-auto-bike-rack-types

Comment: And http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8022/which-bicycle-rack-to-buy-for-my-car

Comment: And http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8137/buying-a-car-with-the-bike-rack-in-mind

Answer (score 5):

*My answer only applies if you will be hauling your bike(s) frequently or somewhat frequently.* My solution may not be worth it for occasional use, because one would need to invest in a trailer hitch for mounting the rack.

Get a trailer hitch like this:[image: typical trailer hitch] (Notice that the "trailer" hitching part is removable and the bike rack fits into that spot) And then choose one of several [trailer hitch bike racks](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8#q=trailer%20hitch%20bike%20racks&hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&prmd=imvns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&ei=qWyHT6OCCseciAKruanPAg&ved=0COUBEK0E&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=8cac8a18d8542941&ix=seb&biw=1191&bih=735).

You may or may not haul a trailer, however, the bikes will ride a hitch mount just fine. With a hitch mount you don't have to worry about overhead clearance or (usually) the inability to open the rear hatch of the car.

My hitch mount can haul 4 bikes, (and I can still open the trunk) but I haven't used the total capacity yet.

Why do I like this?

1. The bike rack locks onto the trailer hitch in 5 minutes or less
2. The bikes are situated in 15 minutes or less.
3. I'm good to go. I don't have to worry about strapping things down or getting the trunk open, or overhead clearance.

Answer (score 3):

The Saris Bones racks are popular and have good quality construction.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Thule rack (on my mini cooper), it works great (takes about 10 seconds to mount a bike), and I can still open the hatch with it on.  It comes in a 1.25 and 2 inch hitch size (the 2 inch version can expand to hold 4 bikes, the 1.25 will hold max of 2 bikes).

[Thule 2 Bike Platform Hitch Rack (917XTR-T2)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004YQAGNM)

It is not a cheap rack, but it is worth the price for the hassle it saves.

Answer (score 0):

Look for something similar to the [Pendle SO](http://www.rutlandcycling.com/262/Pendle-Strap-On-3-Bike-Rack---SO.html). They are good quality, cheap, easy to use, and about the only way to go on a hatchback.

Answer (score 0):

[image: thule trunk rack]

This is a Thule trunk-mounted rack. Typically used on sedans, but it also works on some (not all) hatchbacks and wagons. If you can mount one of these so that the top bar rests on the edge of the hatch, not on the glass, then it should work. But this might be a problem with your Focus - it has a sort of visor at the top of the rear window, right? That part is probably not designed to bear weight, so it wouldn't hold up at all.

I'd look into roof-mounted racks if I were you.